# rails4 solr sunspot multiple core, separated indexes how can I make it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, solr4

```bsh
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0

$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep solr
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    sunspot_solr (2.0.0)
    rsolr (1.0.9)
      sunspot_solr (>= 1.2)
  sunspot_solr!


$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep sunspot
  remote: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git
    sunspot (2.0.0)
    sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
      sunspot (= 2.0.0)
    sunspot_solr (2.0.0)
    sunspot-rails-tester (1.0.0)
      sunspot_rails (>= 1.2)
      sunspot_solr (>= 1.2)
  sunspot-rails-tester
  sunspot_rails!
  sunspot_solr!
```

`http://localhost:8982/solr/#/`
Versions
solr-spec
4.2.0.2013.03.06.22.32.13
solr-impl
4.2.0 1453694 - rmuir - 2013-03-06 22:32:13
lucene-spec
4.2.0
lucene-impl
4.2.0 1453694 - rmuir - 2013-03-06 22:25:29

**what I am trying to do:**
run 2 different solr instances to run at the same time.
separate indexes and everything to search from separated rails environments (ex. production and development).

**what I am facing:**
If I try to run 2 separated solrs, they run and start, but they don't respond as they should.

I ticketed an issue to them, but nobody seems to be answering.
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/435

If anyone has already achieved solr multicore in any ways (different ports, different data directory, or etc), I would like to know how.

Comment: yes, but so much to explain here.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721996/use-one-solr-instance-for-two-rails-apps
I think what's needed is a multicore setup but it's not easy to configure. I've toyed around with it a bit but cannot get it working.