# Use one Solr instance for two Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have a server set up with several Rails apps, two of which are using Solr Sunspot. However, Solr is returning irrelevant results for a given search, and I believe the problem boils down to not having separated Solr/Sunspot to handle two Rails apps.

I have this in one app:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 2.0
    text :body do
      strip_tags body
    end
    time :created_at
  end
end
```

and this in the other:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
  end
end
```

And my sunspot.yml files are basically identical:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/default
    solr_home: solr

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

my solr.xml for both apps reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="default"     instanceDir="." dataDir="default/data"/>
    <core name="development" instanceDir="." dataDir="development/data"/>
    <core name="test"        instanceDir="." dataDir="test/data"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Is there a way to have 1 Solr instance index and deliver results for 2 Rails apps?

I haven't found much documentation on this so am a bit confused as to how to do this.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is a multicore setup.  By default that is how sunspot runs now, except that the cores are for the different rails environments.  See https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/115 for that change.  Following that template I think you need to find one place to keep the config files and data directories, and then update them to list all the cores that it will run.  This post at http://eemglobal.com/2014/07/setup-rails-4-with-sunspot-gem-and-solr-4-7-in-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14/ shows an alternate means, where you add the cores using the solr admin interface and then update the configuration files to match.

Comment: I've tried doing this but my solr admin interface always defaults to using default, development and test environments. Doesn't seem like sunspot was design with multiple apps in mind.

Comment: What do you mean always defaults?  Testing locally in a dev rails environment I've added another core and updated sunspot.yml to use it.  Starting sunspot via the rake task and visiting the admin interface I see four cores (default, development, test, and my new one, alt).  I can stop and restart and still see the same cores.

Perhaps you are deploying via capistrano and wiping/recreating some important solr configuration files every time?

Comment: I think the part I'm getting wrong is, in both Rails apps I am including the sunspot gem, and in both Rails apps I have a solr directory as well as a config/sunspot.yml file. Do I only need one solr directory & sunspot.yml file for both apps? Then I suppose I can add the cores from the admin interface but I'd need to specify that the source is coming from an external app.

Comment: Sounds like you need to designate one app to run solr.  Both apps will have a sunspot.yml, but only one will have a solr.xml.  Define a core for each app (maybe app_name_env).  Make sure that in sunspot.yml each app specifies a path that matches, eg path:/solr/app2_production .  In the end, you should only have one solr directory.

Comment: Sunspot keeps defaulting to having three cores every time I restart the server. I think this might be because in solr.xml, it has this entry: `<solr persistent="false">` so every time I stop and start sunspot, the cores I just created in the admin ui disappear and I always end up with default, development, test. Should I just edit the solr.xml file or should I add cores from the admin interface? To be entirely honest, this is piss-poor design, I don't understand why my question was downvoted it shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Even if I set persistent to "true" and manually edit the solr.xml file with the names of my apps, restarting solr still resets all my cores to default/development/test. Here is my current setup: https://gist.github.com/DaniG2k/49763304cddea7df2481

Comment: I've found that the solr.xml file that's being used is not the one within the Rails app, but within the directory: `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/solr/solr.xml` .... no comment regarding this design choice (-_-)

Comment: Solr is an entirely separate java based project with it's own configuration files.  Sunspot is accomplishing it's goal of making it easy to run Solr in development and talk to Solr servers.  It is not clear what exactly you have going on in your environment, but your focus should be to create a single Solr instance that your applications talk to.  It is 100% okay to do that outside of the Sunspot gem if necessary.  If you want to keep using the gem to run the server, look at the solr_home and data_path options in sunspot.yml configuration, those may help you define and configure Solr

Comment: Is this even possible with sunspot 2.0.0  which appears to be running solr  3.5.0  ?   I have several similar code bases that need to access solr, and I think they are all piling up on the same data dir and ports.